# Is there a way to install pyqt5-tools on Python 3.11?

Tags: python, cmd, pyqt5

I want to download pyqt5-tools to download and use the QtEditor using this command on Windows:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

But when I put in the command in cmd, I get this message:

```
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 144, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 148, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 585, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lszibq72\pyqt5_ab212e2bd45f4304b01a003f265edfc5\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Windows 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zpwp4_go\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

As you see, everything goes fine until the preparing metadata part. I heard that it won't work on versions above 3.9, but is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the wheel file using this code:

```
pip install (location)\pyqt5_plugins-5.15.4.2.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/108).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).